# LeaderBoard mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, discord.py

Есть база данных, там 900 ячеек:
id: айди чела
balance: его баланс
bank: то что у него в банке

Как получить и отсортировать значения эти от самого большого к маленькому (по balance и bank)

Comment: Нужно конкретнее, как сортировать. по остатку? если они равны, то по остатку в банке?

Comment: @falm, в базе данных есть id, bank, balance. Надо сделать что то типо:
1) Ник - 10000

Comment: и чтобы эти 10000 были суммой bank и balance

Comment: Попробуй сагрегировать и отсортировать по полю
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786941/how-to-sort-with-the-sum-of-2-fields-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Крч. Я (ультрагениус) добавила total В базу и во всей экономике прописала где и как изменять total, теперь можно сортировать по total удобно

````
    @commands.command()
    @commands.guild_only()
    async def lb(self, ctx, iters=10):
        rows = self.collection.find(limit=iters).sort("total", -1)
        count = 0
        emb = discord.Embed(title='Топ 10 сервера',
                            color=discord.Color.random())
        for row in rows:
            nam = ctx.guild.get_member(int(row["_id"]))
            if nam is None:
                continue
            total = row["total"]
            emb.add_field(name=f"{str(count + 1)}) {nam}", value=f"{total} <:TrollCoin:927528150643126292>",
                          inline=False)
            count = count + 1
        emb.set_author(name=self.bot.user.name, icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar)
        emb.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar)
        await ctx.reply(embed=emb)
    ```
````

Comment: внутри f стринги значения преобразуются дандер методом `__str__`. Поэтому приводить в строку нет смысла